# Apotomo alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, presenter, apotomo

The information on the home page of the project I'm working has been piling up that now we are looking for something to create a dashboard-like interface.

That's how I found Apotomo, but I'm wondering what would be some alternatives worth looking into.

So far, I've looked through the [Rails Presenters on ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters).

*Thankful for any suggestions to speed-up the development.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) has a nice dashboard, might be worth checking out. Here it is on their [demo](http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin) and the [commented code](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info/blob/master/app/admin/dashboards.rb)